# How does OpenGL arrays layout in shared memory?

Tags: opengl-es, compute-shader

The GLSL ES 3.1 spec said

> `vec4[3][2] a; // size-3 array of size-2 array of vec4`
>
> When in transparent memory (like in a uniform block), the layout is that the 'inner' (right-most in declaration) dimensions iterate faster than the outer dimensions. That is, for the above, the order in
>   memory would be:
>
> low address...a[0][0] a[0][1] a[1][0] a[1][1] a[2][0] a[2][1]...high address

Does it means that memory layout of arrays in shared memory is implementation dependent?

Comment: Can you be more specific? I have troubles to understand your question. Perhaps a code snippet. The shared memory should not be any different than *regular* memory.